# how to wait until NSXmlParser finished with delegate methodS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am giving the nsdata to the xmlparser from the tableview. After parsing is done i want to set the status on the table according to the parsing result . I have done following :

```
    -(BOOL)getTheServerStatus:(NSData *)webData
{
    if (webData==NULL) 
    {
        return FALSE;
    }



    parser=[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:webData];
    parser.delegate=self;

    [parser parse];

    if([strVal isEqualToString:@"ok"])
    {
        return TRUE;   
    }

    else 
    {
        return FALSE;

    }

}
```

But my control returns before parsing is done so i am getting NULL at the table side. Is there any way to wait until all the parsing is done without blocking the main thread?

Comment: I cannot see from the documentation and have not experienced that `NSXMLParser` works asynchronously. When `[parser parse]` returns then the parsing is done or aborted with an error. Are you sure that delegate methods are called after `parse` has returned? Did you check the return value of the `parse` operation for possible errors?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the NSXMLParserDelegate in your class you can find it out through the following delegate method

```
//This method is called when the XML document has finished parsing, do a [self.tableView reloadData]; here
    - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
    {

    }
```

Comment: I want to return the parsed data to another class.

Answer (score 0):

Write a delegate for the NSXMLParser class's parent to notify when the parsing is complete.
The parsing completion is notified by the

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
```

In that method invoke the delegate to parent class informing the parsing is complete.

Answer (score -1):

Use the

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
```

delegate method.

Comment: I want to return the parsed data to another class